# jQuery: find elements by word from the text string

Tags: jquery

I have a text for example :"hello stackoverflow, how are you?"
and i going to find all elements whose that contain one or more words from this text,please help me about this in jquery

Comment: Sorry to say that, but SO is not a place to ask others to do your homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$(":contains(hello),:contains(stackoverflow)")
```

While this will technically work, I imagine that will be wildly inefficient on any reasonably sized page.  If you can restrict your initial search set at all (only spans, or only anchors, or anything like that) it will help immensely.